# how to pin date at bottom of header bar in chat application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have chat application which is implemented using SingleChildScrollView, I want to pin the dates of chat on top after certain scrolling position is reached i.e when dates reaches the top.

heres the data I'm getting

```
var list = [
    {
      "01-01-2020": [
        {"10:20": "Title"},
        {"10:30": "Test"},
        {"11:40": "testing"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "02-01-2020": [
        {"10:21": "Title"},
        {"10:35": "Test"},
        {"11:45": "testing"}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: how do you want it can post an image ??

Comment: every thing is working fine just the date should be pin to top on scroll like whatsapp

Comment: how to achieve pushpin in flutter with the example given
https://materializecss.com/pushpin-demo.html

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header

Comment: can i use this idea to stick the dates in my chat app without using the header

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for something like this image
where dates are grouped to my list and on scroll the dates are stacked at the bottom of header
got solution and used "grouped_list" library

[image]

how can I achieve similar thing without using library